# main.dart.js file loads twice in Flutter Web App causing performance issue

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app, and I'm experiencing an issue where the `main.dart.js` file is loaded twice when I open the app.

I've also attached a screenshot depicting the problem to provide more clarity. Can you help me understand why the `main.dart.js` file is being loaded twice and suggest any improvements to the code that might resolve this issue?

[image]

What I observed when I open it the first time it loads only one without the version and the second time it loads both!

However, I'm not sure what is causing this behavior. I believe the following code snippet might be related to the issue:

Code from `index.html` file:

```
function loadMainDartJs() {
  if (scriptLoaded) {
    return;
  }
  scriptLoaded = true;
  var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');

  scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js?v=2.1.8+87_1'; // the payload is the version number

  scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
  document.body.append(scriptTag);
}
// Code causing the issue?
```

Comment: The snippet from the index.html seems to use the old style for loading the main.dart.js file. Try creating a new flutter project and have a look at the index.html to see how it is done in new projects.